# Is there a traditional Japanese kana song or otherwise how are babies familiarised with kana?

Tags: kana, child-speech

I have a newborn son from my Japanese wife. I try to sing to him. I sing the alphabet song (English). Japanese kana and their order is the same value for dictionaries. My wife says there isn't one but she isn't traditionally trained. Is there a kana syllabary song?

I found this- I don't think its based on Hakushū Kitahara song.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBfb4UK4-MM

Comment: The video you link is based on the Kitahara poem, as it says in the title.

Comment: When I first started learning Japanese (as a second language), my instructor had us listen to 日本語のおけいこ: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXvITpB4j0c.

Comment: On YouTube you can find [lots of "あいうえおの歌" (≒ABC song) made for children and learners](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2142719656896663501), but one I was familiar with in my childhood was not to be found there. I doubt there is a single, famous, traditional alphabet song everyone must know.

Comment: I don't think we have common mnemonic devices other than reciting 五十音図. Well, there's traditional いろは歌 but it no longer makes sense in today's language... It's also good to see how Hawaiian people, whose language is no less syllabic than Japanese, teach their children the alphabet: https://youtu.be/eEYs9wOUxsE

Comment: I don't need a mnemonic device- he's too young to really learn Japanese but it could be great if it was a song or it was a poem that included all the syllabary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite a bit more sophisticated than the "alphabet song", there is a wonderful poem by 北原白秋 ([Hakushū Kitahara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakush%C5%AB_Kitahara)) called 五十音. It goes like this

> ### 五十音
>
> [水馬]{あめんぼ}赤いな。ア、イ、ウ、エ、オ。
> [浮藻]{うきも}に[小蝦]{こえび}もおよいでる。
>
> 柿{かき}の木、栗{くり}の木。カ、キ、ク、ケ、コ。
> [啄木鳥]{きつつき}、こつこつ、枯{か}れけやき。
>
> [大角豆]{ささげ}に酢{す}をかけ、サ、シ、ス、セ、ソ。
> その魚{うお}[浅瀬]{あさせ}で刺{さ}しました。
>
> 立ちましょ[喇叭]{らっぱ}で、タ、チ、ツ、テ、ト。
> トテトテタッタと飛び立った。
>
> [蛞蝓]{なめくじ}のろのろ、ナ、ニ、ヌ、ネ、ノ。
> [納戸]{なんど}にぬめってなにねばる。
>
> [鳩]{はと}ぽっぽ、ほろほろハ、ヒ、フ、ヘ、ホ。
> [日向]{ひなた}のお部屋にゃ笛を吹く。
>
> [蝸牛]{まいまい}[螺旋巻]{ねじまき}、マ、ミ、ム、メ、モ。
> 梅の実落ちても見もしまい。
>
> [焼栗]{やきぐり}、ゆで[栗]{ぐり}ヤ、イ、ユ、エ、ヨ。
> 山田に灯{ひ}のつく宵{よい}の家{いえ}。
>
> [雷鳥]{らいちょう}は寒{さむ}かろ、ラ、リ、ル、レ、ロ。
> [蓮花]{れんげ}が咲いたら、[瑠璃]{るり}の鳥。
>
> わい、わい、わっしょい。ワヰウヱヲ。
> [植木屋]{うゑきや}、[井戸換へ]{ゐどがへ}、お祭{まつり}だ。

According to [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%94%E5%8D%81%E9%9F%B3#.E5.8C.97.E5.8E.9F.E7.99.BD.E7.A7.8B.E3.81.AE.E4.BA.94.E5.8D.81.E9.9F.B3) it was first published in 1922 in a magazine called *Taikan* (大観)

> 1922年、雑誌『大観』1月号に上梓されたものを初出とし、…

so I haven't been able to find a primary source, although it seems to be reproduced in several "collected works" (e.g. in these two books (Amazon links), [北原白秋100選](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%90%8D%E4%BD%9C%E7%AB%A5%E8%AC%A1-%E5%8C%97%E5%8E%9F%E7%99%BD%E7%A7%8B100%E9%81%B8-%E4%B8%8A%E7%94%B0-%E4%BF%A1%E9%81%93/dp/4394902339/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1438722272&sr=8-1&keywords=4394902339) and [白秋全集〈25〉童謡集 1](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E7%99%BD%E7%A7%8B%E5%85%A8%E9%9B%86%E3%80%8825%E3%80%89%E7%AB%A5%E8%AC%A1%E9%9B%86-1-%E5%8C%97%E5%8E%9F-%E7%99%BD%E7%A7%8B/dp/4000909657/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1438722386&sr=8-1&keywords=4000909657)).

Comment: Do you have a primary source for that poem and maybe a video of it spoken at least?

Comment: Videos here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsURPvciWPo or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVxud8ArqfM or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0c0cof9WGkA. Here with aerobics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4f3nLeT9lz4

Answer (score 0):

[Iroha uta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iroha) is not exactly a baby song but I think it deserves a mention as it contains all shapes of the syllabary.