# Is the layout of this text supposed to resemble a style of poem?

Tags: poetry

While playing a Japanese video game, I became curious about the layout of these book pages that appear each time you finish a chapter of the game.

[image]

The text of each page summarizes one of the chapters, and is laid out in six lines. Each line contains 13 characters, grouped together into 4-4-5 character long units, resulting in a column-like look.

For example, the first two lines read,

> そだって　あばれた　ガソリンゴ
>
> なんとか　たおした　いのちがけ

Since the form is so schematic I thought this might be modeled to be a kind of Japanese poem. Knowing next to nothing about Japanese poetry, I researched the Wikipedia article on the topic, but couldn't find anything that would correspond with this scheme.

Is the layout of this text supposed to be reminiscent of a form of poetry, or is it more likely to have been made up by the writer?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13819/are-haiku-typically-padded-when-read-aloud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this 4-4-5 (or 4-4-7) rhythm has a nice ring (語呂がいい) to the ears of Japanese. Nicopedia even maintains a [list of words which happen to have such 4-4-5 beats](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E4%B8%83%E4%BA%94%E8%AA%BF%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7).

Kitahara Hakushu's [あめんぼの歌](http://mikumaku.com/nihon/02amenbo.htm) is one of the best-known poems which uses this pattern throughout the lines. The lyrics of the theme song of [水戸黄門](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mito_K%C5%8Dmon) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhDHkB-GQhg); [full lyrics](http://www.utamap.com/showkasi.php?surl=F04410)) follow this 4-4-5 pattern.

オリエンタルラジオ is a comedy duo that uses this 4-4-5 (or 4-4-7) beats in their bits ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V92UD5Gb8Y0)). You can hear that their punch lines basically follow this rhythm:

[image: 4-4-5]

Nicopedia says this pattern can be called 七五調【しちごちょう】, but I'm not sure about that, because 七五調 usually refers to the 5-7-5 pattern of haiku/waka.

Comment: Hearing this, I'm pretty sure I've heard similar songs in the past and wondered about the peculiar meter.

Comment: Your link to あめんぼの歌 is broken. However, you appear to be referring to what I've seen (published) as a poem titled 五十音. I have reproduced this poem in [this answer](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/26175/1628).

Comment: As for the explanation for 七五調, what Nicopedia says is correct rather than this post.